# IOS Tab Bar Sliding

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to make tab bar with sliding (or may be swipe is right word?) effect of changing ViewControllers.

I create two ViewControllers with TableView on whole screen, but with restrictions - top edge of table not overlap top layout guide.

I link this ViewControllers with TabBarController and when I use default animation - it's OK, work fine. But I want sliding animation and do something like (swift3):

```
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    animateSliding(fromController: selectedViewController, toController: viewController)
    return true
}

func animateSliding(fromController: UIViewController?, toController: UIViewController?) {
    let fromView: UIView = fromController!.view;
    let toView: UIView = toController!.view;

    fromView.superview?.addSubview(toView);
    toView.frame.origin.x = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width;

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3,
                   animations: {
                    toView.frame.origin.x = 0;
                    fromView.frame.origin.x -= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width;
                   },
                   completion: nil);
}
```

(it's not complete animation, just sample)

Now I have animation I wanted but second's ViewController's table overlap top guide when appear (when slide over first viewController). If I change position ViewControllers in TabBar (first became second and second became first) situation change - not first controller's table overlap top guide (when appear)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [XLPagerTabStrip](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip)? I believe that it is pretty similar to what you want to achive.

If not, you can base your code in that implementation.

Comment: I have a problem with it - can't "import" xD
But I'll try again, thx.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip#installation) there is some information about how to install it, but If you are having issues with the installation I recommend you to post them here with the tag _''XLPagerTabStrip''_